# Visual studio 2013, how to carry text file over to deployment package?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vsto

I'm writing a VSTO add-in for Word 2010.
I have a text file named "test.txt".
The add-in will read the file and add the content to a listbox line by line.
I set Build Action of the file to "Content", but after compiling and installing the add-in, it said it could not locate the file.

I don't have much experience with Visual Studio and VSTO in general. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can embed it as resource, also you can add a string entry in `My.Resources`, then if you really need it to be a physical file, create it when you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a resource file to your project and access the file using My.Resource

1. Add a Resource File (*.resx) to your project.
2. Goto Resource File > resource Add Resource
3. Add Existing File
4. Browse to your *.txt file
5. Open

Now to access your resource you can use the code below:

**Create physical file from resource:** (Must import System.IO for File & Path or add full reference)

```
        Dim fullFilePath As String = Path.GetTempPath() & "myPlugin/UserAgreement.txt"
        File.WriteAllBytes(fullFilePath, My.Resources.TxtResources.UserAgreement)
```

**Access text from resource as string:**

```
        Dim fileString as String = My.Resources.TxtResources.UserAgreement.ToString();
```

Comment: I also need to write to the file. Resource files are read-only, is that right?

Comment: That is correct. However you could could write the embedded file to the temp directory if the file doesnt exist already using the code above then write to it and if the file does exist in the temp directory use that file instead of the embedded resource